# Double Slit Experiment: What would happen if the slit material was a detector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the double slit experiment, if the actual slit material itself was a detector plate, would it collapse the wavefunction?

Comment: A slit is a hole and represents an absence of material.

Comment: Yes, if you know which slit the particle flies through, the wave function is collapsed at the slit. To know this you need to interact with the particle at the slit. Even if the interaction does not change the trajectory (e.g. a gentle microwave sensing heavy atoms of cesium without diverting them), the very fact of interaction requires the particle to come to existence as a particle flying through only one slit rather than an abstract wave of probability propagating through both slits.

Comment: If you put a metal plate (or some more sophisticated kind of detector) instead of a *slit*, this slit will interact with the wave function, change its behaviour and effectively lead to a collapse of the wave function.