# Detecting particles that do not make it through double slits, do observations match those after the slits?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, double-slit-experiment

I suppose we have 4 conditions to examine :

```
{ single particle | beam } * { with eraser | without eraser }
```

I suppose we have to get the same results that those that are observed behind the slits in the classical version of the experiment, that is :

```
- particle with eraser : even distribution, no interference fringes.
- particle without eraser : interference fringes.
- beam with eraser : even distribution, no interference fringes.
- beam without eraser : interference fringes.
```

The last one maybe would be a significant result for QT. So, has this been done yet ?

Alternative formulation of the question : was the double-slit experiment ever executed with slits cut in a detection screen, and what were the results ?

---

I did read this question :

[Double Slit Experiment: What would happen if the slit material was a detector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/404603/double-slit-experiment-what-would-happen-if-the-slit-material-was-a-detector)

...but I think it does not really treat the same subject matter.

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by the eraser?

Comment: that : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment